# Is it possible to construct a PySpark statement from strings?

Tags: pyspark

Consider

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

statement = F.when(F.col("col1") < 0.5, F.lit(0.5))

str_statement = str(statement)
```

yields

```
"Column<'CASE WHEN (col1 < 0.5) THEN 0.5 END'>"
```

Is it possible to take a string like this and without writing a custom parser recreate the `statement`?

Comment: You mean the vice-versa operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql part of the string can be used as parameter for [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html) to recreate the original column object.

```python
str_statement = "Column<'CASE WHEN (col1 < 0.5) THEN 0.5 END'>"

import re
sql_expr = re.search("Column<'(.*)'>", str_statement).group(1)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
statement = F.expr(sql_expr)
```